# Access single object in model using Metalsmith and swig

Tags: swig-template, metalsmith, yaml-front-matter

I have a json data file with multiple objects with named keys in it.

```
{
  "berlin:" : {
    "location": "Berlin",
    "folder": "berlin-2016"
  },
  "seattle" : {
    "location": "Seattle ",
    "folder": "seattle-2016"
  }
}
```

In my content file I would like to specify which object in the model to use and then refer to that in swig. Something like this:

```
---
model:
  conference: conferences['berlin']
---    

{{ model.conference.location }}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You could use a custom plugin to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely possible with metalsmith. I don't have a complete picture of your build process, but for this solution you'll have to use the [metalsmith javascript api](https://github.com/metalsmith/metalsmith#api):

./data.json

```json
{
  "berlin:" : {
    "location": "Berlin",
    "folder": "berlin-2016"
  },
  "seattle" : {
    "location": "Seattle ",
    "folder": "seattle-2016"
  }
}
```

./build.js

```javascript
// Dependencies
var metalsmith = require('metalsmith');
var layouts = require('metalsmith-layouts');

// Import metadata
var metadata = require('./data.json');

// Build
metalsmith(__dirname)
  // Make data available
  .metadata(data)

  // Process templates
  .use(layouts('swig'))

  // Build site
  .build(function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

Then run `node build.js` in your root project folder to build. In your templates the data from `data.json` would then be available as `{{ berlin.location }}`.

You can also do this without the javascript api (which I don't recommend because you lose some flexibility), in which case you would use a plugin (for example: [metalsmith-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/metalsmith-json))